# Find a maximum triangle that lies on a polyline (with constraints)

Tags: geometry, optimization, approximation

If there's a polyline (a GPS track, actually) with a lot of points (could be several thousand), that looks like this

[image: initial line]

1) How can I find such a triangle with the biggest possible perimeter, that its vertices belong to the polyline? In addition, it have to satisfy some constraint - for example, this one below satisfies 28% leg rule (the shortest leg must not be less than 28% of the total leg distance).

[image: triangle]

2) A related problem; although, I suppose, it should be easier. How can I approximate this polyline with a much simpler broken line with N breakpoints? Like in the example above (4 breakpoints).

[image: turnpoints]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could iterate ovedr all point triples and check each. To make things slightly more effective, you could skip looking for third points if a pair you're investigating can only lead to triangles smaller than the best known so far, avvording to that $28\%$ rule.
2. Depends on how you measure error. Conceptually you could again try all possible break points and remember the best. For more efficient approasches, you might start by reading [How to intelligently degrade or smooth GIS data (simplifying polygons)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1849928/1468366), the [Wikipedia article on the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm) and the alternatives and survey papers mentioned therein. Most such approaches are controlled by a bound on the error, not by the number of segments, but you might be able to adapt them.